# Is Text-to-speech API or react-speech-kit supports in react version 18?

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, accessibility, text-to-speech

Is any npm package I can use in my react project to implement text to speech functionality in my web application. I want o to implement it in a specific area of my dashboard for disabled persons to achieve maximum web accessibility.

Comment: https://github.com/morganney/tts-react

Answer (score 1):

The [Web Speech APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API), one of which is speech synthesis, are available on browsers supporting them regardless of which version of React you might be using, and even when you're not using React at all.